# In the Dirac single-particle theory, what's the physical difference between these two spinors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-equation

Let's take a unidimensional case of a free particle moving in the z axis. A complete basis of spinors is
$$
u_1(p) = \sqrt{\frac{E + mc^2}{2mc^2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{pc}{E + mc^2} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
u_2(p) = \sqrt{\frac{E + mc^2}{2mc^2}}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \frac{-pc}{E + mc^2} \end{pmatrix}\\
u_3(p) = \sqrt{\frac{|E| + mc^2}{2mc^2}}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{-pc}{|E| + mc^2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\\
u_4(p) = \sqrt{\frac{|E| + mc^2}{2mc^2}}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{pc}{|E| + mc^2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\\
$$
where the first two are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with a positive energy eigenvalue, and the last two are eigenstates with negative eigenvalue.

Any state can be expressed as a linear combination of this complete basis as:

$$
\psi(z,t) = \int dp \sum_{r=1,2} \sqrt{\frac{mc^2}{E V}} c_{p,r} u_r(p) e^{ipz/\hbar - iEt/\hbar} + \int dp \sum_{r=3,4} \sqrt{\frac{mc^2}{|E| V}} c_{p,r} u_r(p) e^{ipz/\hbar + i|E|t/\hbar}
$$
where $c_{p,r}$ are the Fourier coefficents.

Now consider these two states:

$$ 
\psi_1(z,0) = \begin{pmatrix}
\phi(z) \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$ 
\psi_2(z,0) = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0 \\
\phi(z)  \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $\phi(z)$ can be taken, for example, to be a gaussian.

Both $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are eigenstates of $\Sigma_3$ with the same (+1) eigenvalue. Both have the same probability density. I would think that $\psi_1$ was a positive energy spinor while $\psi_2$ is a negative energy one. But if you calculate the Fourier coefficients via

$$
c_{p,r} = \int u^{\dagger}_r(p) \psi e^{-i p z/\hbar} dz, \ \ \ \ r= 1,2,3,4
$$

you find that both $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ have negative energy components. Both have $c_{p,2} = c_{p,4} = 0$, but the coefficients $c_{p,1}$ and $c_{p,3}$ are non-zero for both states. They are just "flipped" between the states ($\psi_1$'s $c_{p,1}$ is equal to $\psi_2$'s $c_{p,3}$, and vice versa).

So what's the difference between both states? What's one observable which can discern between the two?

Comment: An antiparticle is distinguishable from a particle

Comment: I'm talking about electron states though. Both $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ describe electrons, each of which has positive AND negative energy components. I'm aware that a pure negative-energy electron state corresponds to a positron state with opposite momentum, spin, and energy, but I don't see how that helps here. I do think you're on the right track though, so I'd appreciate some elaboration.

Comment: The complete basis you have described is 4 dimensional, not infinite dimensional.

Comment: The basis I described spans the 4-dimensional "discrete" part of the Hilbert space. The equation I wrote for the Fourier expansion of $\psi$ includes the entirety of the Hilbert space, including the contiuous, spatial degree of freedom. I did not think it was necessary to show explicitly the basis of the position Hilbert space, as that is carried over unchanged from non-relativistic QM.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion, vectors with functions as coefficients are a pretty common occurrence in Quantum Mechanics and all of physics.

Comment: My point is that using a Gaussian here is a red herring. Replace the gaussian with a “1”. Now what is the physical difference between these states?